# The copy() method in Python does not work properly

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that I would like to make a duplicate of and do some operations on the duplicated version without affecting the original one. I use ".copy()" method but for some reason it doesn't work! Here is my code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,2])
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [x, x, x], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})

duplicate = df.copy()
duplicate['A'].values[0][[0,1]] = 0

print(duplicate)
print(df)

        A  B
0  [0, 0]  4
1  [0, 0]  5
2  [0, 0]  6
        A  B
0  [0, 0]  4
1  [0, 0]  5
2  [0, 0]  6
```

As you can see "df" (the original dataset) gets affected as well. Does anyone know why, and how this should be done correctly?

Comment: Do dataframes implement `deepcopy`?

Comment: This is a shallow copy, it only copies the dataframe elements, not the numpy arrays that are contained in them.

Comment: `df.copy(deep = True)`

Comment: @JuanC deep = True is the default that I'm using.

Comment: @Barmar The default in copy() is deep and not shallow.

Comment: @JuanC from the documentation: **When deep=True, data is copied but actual Python objects will not be copied recursively, only the reference to the object.** So it doesn't copy the numpy arrays.

Comment: having python objects like an array is probably not a good idea in the first place. In any case, you can just manually copy that column, `df['A'] = [x.copy() for x in df['A']]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Do you know a better data structure? Perhaps using list instead of dataframe?

Comment: it really depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to train a neural network and each row is an input. The network takes vactors as input. Perhaps I'll open a new topic for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is actually in the list value rather than the df itself. When you are copying the dataframe, even if it's by default a deep copy, it's not doing deepcopy on the value itself, so if the value is a list, the reference is copied over, you can tell this by the fact that even though you only tried to modify the first row, but all values of `A` in your duplicate are modified.

The proper way is probably:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from copy import deepcopy # <- **

x = np.array([1,2])
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [x, x, x], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})

duplicate = df.copy()
duplicate['A'] = duplicate["A"].apply(deepcopy)  # <- **

duplicate['A'].values[0][[0,1]] = 0

print(duplicate)
print(df)

        A  B
0  [0, 0]  4
1  [1, 2]  5
2  [1, 2]  6

        A  B
0  [1, 2]  4
1  [1, 2]  5
2  [1, 2]  6
```